# An example of finding the irreducible representations of G over C

Tags: representation-theory

I have an example in my lecture notes but I really don't understand what it is doing at each step so I was wondering if someone could help me work through it so that I can then do the problem sheet questions I have to do. The example I am looking at is below and I am looking to answer the question;

**Let $G=C_2\times C_3 = \langle g_1,g_2 \mid g_1^2=g_2^3=1, g_1g_2=g_2g_1\rangle$. Write down all the irreducible representations of G over C.**

Example. Let $G = V_4$, the Klein four group and let $V$ be the regular $\mathbb CG$-module with basis $\{e, f, g, h\}$. Then $G$ is cyclic, so there are four 1-dimensional irreducible representations of $G$.

**Why? If $G=C_2\times C_3$ then can we expect to find 6 irreducible representations? Why are they 1 dimensional? Will they be in the question I am trying to do?**

If $\rho$ is such a representation then $\rho(f)^2 = \rho(g)^2 = (1)$ and $ρ(h) = ρ(f)ρ(g)$. So the four irreducible representations must be

ρ1 :e ->(1) f-> (1) g->(1) h->(1)

ρ2 :e→(1) f->(-1) g->(1) h-> (-1)

ρ3 :e→(1) f->(1) g->(-1) h->(-1)

ρ4 :e→(1) f-> (-1) g->(-1) h->(1)

**Where did these values come from?**

***So for my question I have got as far as to say that $p(g_1)^2=p(g_2)^3=1$ and $p(g_1g_1)=p(g_2g_1)$ but no further..***

I would really appreciate any help with answering questions like this, I have yet to find a good example in books or my lecture notes.
Thanks

Comment: In the example $G$ is not cyclic, so I don't know why it says that. However, since $G$ is abelian, the statement about the number of irreducible representations is correct. In general, if $G$ is abelian, then $G$ has $|G|$ irreducible representations, and these are all $1$-dimensional. Further, a representation is uniquely determined by where it sends a set of generators for the group, and any element $g\in G$ must be sent to an element $x$ such that $x^{|g|} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As Tobias pointed out, it is important that both groups are Abelian.

I recommend James and Liebeck's Representations and Characters of Groups for an introduction to the topic. It is very detailed. In particular the case of Abelian groups is treated at length in Chapter 9 "Schur's Lemma".